# Autenticação windows com selenium

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testes, selenium-webdriver

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando realizar uma autentação windows com selenium, porém é apresentado o erro abaixo..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há outra forma pra realizar esse tipo de autenticação?

Comment: Você consegue localizar o alert utilizando o Selenium? O Selenium não consegue manipular caixas de interação do Sistema Operacional (como a de seleção de certificados digitais, por exemplo), pois são diferentes dos alertas dos navegadores..

Comment: Esquece o Selenium: Não vais conseguir manipular nada do windows com ele. Experimenta o autoit (pesquisa no google)